# Python Selenium Not Executing Javascript from Google Tag Manager

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I am running a unittest on an api which is called via google tag manager to inject the script tags which pull down a javascript file. For example, gtm injects the following:

```
<script src="http://www.example.com/js/file.js"></script>
```

In the file `file.js` there is javascript that executes to process visitor information and sends it to our api. This whole process works fine for site visitors, but fails in Python Selenium, using PhantomJS. Viewing the page source, I can see that the data is pulled down from gtm correctly, and a request for `file.js` is made to our servers, but the code inside never executes. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong? Below is an extract from my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true'])
driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)
driver.get('https://www.example.com')
print(driver.page_source)
cookies = {item['name']: item for item in driver.get_cookies()}
print(cookies)
```

Since gtm loads at the end of the page, could their be the potential that it doesn't execute the associated javascript?

Comment: Have you tried adding a small delay to make sure the page loads completely? e.g.,`time.sleep(2)` after `driver.get(...)` and before the first `print`

Comment: Yea, I tried doing a 10 second delay and still received the same issue.

Comment: I noticed you mentioned it works for visitors, but does it run in selenium with a different webdriver? I normally debug js that way using the browser to step through the code, then switch back to running headless once everything is running smoothly.

Comment: I am trying to automate if GTM tag is being fired on particular page, can you please let me know how you did that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the javascript was executing, but it was erroring out because I was attempting to get the Timezone via the Intl library which is not natively supported in PhantomJS. I determined that this was the error with the following: `driver.get_log('browser')` and examining the output.